# How to float a top bar?

Tags: html, css, scroll

I want to find a drupal theme that has a bar like Twitter's top bar at http://dev.twitter.com that stays there. If there is not one, how do I replicate that similar effect in a Drupal 7?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also check out Twitter's excellent [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) project for examples.  See [here](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/#navigation) for the details.  They call it a top bar.  Also you could use Bootstrap as a starting point for a Drupal custom theme if you want to roll your own.

Answer (score 14):

While I don't know of any Drupal themes, I know how to recreate the effect -- to pin an element to the top of the viewport, use CSS's `position: fixed`:

```
#topbar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0
}
```

You'll also probably want to put a top margin on the rest of your content, so that it doesn't cover it up.